# Jackson Mixin: to deserialize routeId

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I am using Jackson Mixin to deserialize mongo object and the Mixin looks as below.

```
public interface MyMixin {
  /**
   * Mixin to set key value for pojo.
   * @param key key
   * @param value value
   */
  @JsonAnySetter
  void put(String key, Object value);
}
```

The mixin works really well for all fields including list except for the id field.
The pojo looks as below.

```
public class MyPojo {
  @JsonProperty("_id")
  @javax.persistence.Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

The exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: (String)"{"_id": {"$oid": "5e049cb30eb7811fec0c7029"}

I understand that its failing to deserialize string from a nested json.
One way through which I solved the problem is via writing custom mapper

```
 public static MyPojo map(final Document document) {
    final MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    pojo.setUd(document.getObjectId("_id").toHexString());
    // set other fields
    return pojo;
```

But this requires change is mapper whenever there is a change in pojo, adding/removing fields.
The Mixin works without any change, How shall I update my Mixin to handle objectId as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can have a mixin to handle this kind of case in a generic way.   I propose a solution that has not much to do with mixin but gives one generic way to deserialize such fields. First create a class to represent the json id:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class OidId {
    @JsonProperty("$oid")
    private String oid;
}
```

Then an abstract class to have the mapping stuff:

```
public abstract class HasOidId {

    // moved from MyPojo
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private String id;

    @JsonSetter("_id") // this is the trigger for mapping "_id" stufff
    public void setId(OidId oidId) {
        this.id = oidId.getOid();
    }
}
```

Then let `MyPojo` extend above:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MyPojo extends HasOidId {
    private String name;
}
```